# How to get a reference to control in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I have a RadMap control  in my MVVM app, and I need to get the coordinates of some point on a map.

Without using MVVM I could do it using the following code:

```
 Location.GetCoordinates(this.map1, new Point(5, 5));
```

The question is how to do it in MVVM ? I can't use this.map1

Comment: is there any Dependency property in  the radMap control that holds the Coordinate.If it is,then create a poco object in your viewmodel and wire it to the xaml.

Comment: the View is responsible for passing user input to the VM, the preferred method is binding but as long as the event model isn't doing anything to the data in the VM then processing the event and pushing the data into the VM from code behind isn't against MVVM, though is not a preferred solution

Comment: a more MVVM way would be to define a Command in the VM and then use input binding to bind the MouseUp event to the command